# Deploy Django-cms on one click django installation – Digital Ocean

Tags: django, deployment, django-cms, digital-ocean

i'm searching for a fast way to deploy django-cms on digital ocean. I tried to use one click installation django.
I did the following:

```
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
aptitude install libpq-dev python-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev
```

I created and uploaded requirements.txt and installed it in:

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

then i upload my django-cms project to `home/django` directory, i named it `django_project`
just for not renaming nginx/gunicorn path. after i finished with:

```
python manage.py syncdb 
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py createsuperuser 
service gunicorn restart
```

and looked at my droplets ip and surprise at first sight everything working fine but then i noticed that django-cms admin bar has no styles, most of the links not working and so on…

here a screenshot of admin bar:
[image]

anyone can help me out im trying since days to deploy django-cms without success i tried a lot of tutorials like [Digital Oceanns django-cms tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-and-install-django-cms-on-a-debian-7-or-ubuntu-13-vps) but my problem there was that everything just working with virtualenv activated on port 8000.
Getting crazy, django-cms deployment seems to be very difficult for a beginner like me – glad for every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finaly i found out what was missing. Here the full process of deploying django-cms to the Digital Ocean – django-one-click-installation

Create droplet I used Ubuntu 14.4 + application django

```
aptitude update
aptitude upgrade
aptitude install libpq-dev python-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev
```

Upload your django-cms to `home/django/django_project/django_project` and install `requirements.txt`, don't forget to update Database in settings.py. If you rename your project folder remember to change the path to your static files in gunicorn and nginx like here:
[digital ocean one click install django](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-django-one-click-install-image)

then:

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate 
python manage.py createsuperuser 
python manage.py collectstatic
```

collectstatic packs all the static files of your app and your site-packeges to a static folder, make sure that it is in the right place dont forget to set the right media and static path in the 
`/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django` file
then:

```
secvice nginx restart (in case u modified default configuration)
service gunicorn restart
```

everything should work now if you've problems with uploading images or static files make sure your settings.py MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL point on the right folder.
Gl hope it's usefull